# JPA - ManyToOne: Join columns and query tables without using whole Object

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have an `OrderItemEntity` that I want to associate to a specific `OrderEntity` in a *ManyToOne* relationship (many OrderItems belong to one order).

I want to join the columns of both tables with @JoinColumn, but without using the (Java-Object) OrderEntity.

Reason: Whenever I want to query the OrderItemRepository (e.g. list all OrderItems to a specific order) I have to supply an OrderEntity (`findByOrderId(OrderEntity orderEntity)`), but instead, I'd like to supply a simple OrderId. Is there a better way to accomplish that?

**My OrderItemEntity Class:**

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class OrderItemEntity {

    @Id
    private String orderItemId;

    private int quantity;
    private double subtotal;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "orderId")
    private OrderEntity orderId;

    public OrderItemEntity() {
    }
}
```

**Repository Interface:**

```
@Repository
public interface OrderItemEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<OrderItemEntity, String>{

    ArrayList<OrderItem> findByOrderId(OrderEntity orderEntity);

}
```

**Method in Service-Class to query the repository**

```
@Override
public ArrayList<OrderItem> getOrderItems(String orderId) {
    return orderItemEntityRepository.findByOrderId(new OrderEntity(orderId, null, null));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First change the property to `private OrderEntity order;` and change the method in the repository to `ArrayList<OrderItem> findByOrder_Id(Long orderEntityId);`, then you just pass the order entity id to get the entities.